# What is difference between scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating: and scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollviewdelegate

`scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating`: delegate method is called on finger up as it is moving.(from `UIScrollView.h`)
But, `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` delegate method is also called when same state.
(called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards) -> from UIScrollView.h)

When I test, they are always called together.
I don't know what is the difference.

Actually, I should know when a scroll will be begun deceleration.
`scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` is always called on finger up.

Answer (score 0):

No both has differrent states

`scrollViewDidEndDragging` - The scroll view sends this message when the user’s finger touches up after dragging content. The decelerating property of UIScrollView controls deceleration.

`scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` - The scroll view calls this method as the user’s finger touches up as it is moving during a scrolling operation; the scroll view will continue to move a short distance afterwards. The decelerating property of UIScrollView controls deceleration.
[Refer Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:)

Comment: These are really same state? I can't understand why the two methods exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag the scroll view so slowly that after your finger is up, the scroll view won't move, then `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` will be called, with `decelerate == NO`, while the `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` not being called.

Both the delegate methods will be called when you drag fast enough.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference in case of the parameter decelerate == NO.
But if I drag fast enough, I can't understand why the two methods exist.